# Substituting string from list into new variable names

Tags: python, string, exec

I'm trying to create new object variables while referencing a list of strings. I'm trying to use exec() and .format to fill in the variable names but I keep getting syntax errors:

```
df_MMM=<__main__.stock_ object at 0x7fde41682890>
       ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax*

This is my code:

```
class stock_:
    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self.ticker=ticker
    def frame(self):
        return web.DataReader(self.ticker,'yahoo',start, end)

list_of_stocks=['MMM','AXP',"AMGN",'AAPL','BA','CAT','CVX','CSCO','KO']

for i in list_of_stocks:
    exec("df_{}={}".format(i,stock_(i)))
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: using `exec` is almost always the wrong solution. But letting that pass for now - what is the code you're trying to get it to execute? `_stock(i)` is an object whose string representation you are including in the code string you're passing to `exec`, unless you override the `__str__` method it will always display in the kind of format you're seeing in the syntax error. It's not at all clear to me what you want to happen here.

Comment: From your class and the method you declared it seems that your goal is to store data retrieved from some web service. If that's the case, a list of dictionaries (one per ticker) should serve you well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate your format values

```
exec("df_{}={}".format(i,stock_(i)))
```

Did you trace your values (standard debugging practice)?  I think not.
`stock_(i)` is an instance of the class ... an object.  It's string representation is what you see in your error message.  Are you trying to generate a line of code to do the instantiation?  Your line above does the instantiation, and gives the resulting string representation to `exec`.  Perhaps this:

```
exec("df_{}=stock_('{}')".format(i,i))
```

This will evaluate only `i`, and place that value into your string, such as

```
df_MMM=stock_('MMM')
```

---

I need to raise the x-y problem I see here.  You're making a somewhat arbitrary set of new variables; I worry about how you might be using them.  I strongly suspect that a *much* better way is to key a dict with the stock symbol -- make one dict, rather than nine new variables.

```
stock_table = {}
for i in list_of_stocks:
    stock_table[i] = stock_(i)
```

You can also do this in one line with a dict comprehension.
The coding is left as an exercise for the student.  :-)

Comment: Dear user, this is very useful! Thank you for your help:)